# Formatting and styling dynamic data received from DataTable in the view

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am currently using ASP.NET core 2.1 and bootstrap 4 building a web app. I am using dynamic stored procedure to return data table from Sql server based on user selections. Once the data is filled in the DataTable, I pass the model containing the DataTable to the view and do ForEach loop to populate the table headers and rows as the columns are dynamic (depends on what the user selected).

My question is how to apply formatting and styling to the table displayed to the user? For example, if the table has amount column, I want to display $27.87 instead of 27.87 and right justified to the column, and if it has Date column, display the date in the standard date format and centered to its column and so on

Here is my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAction(ViewModel model)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Test", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TestId", model.TestId));
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

    da.Fill(model.ReportResults);

    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();

    return View(model);
}
```

and here is my view:

```
@using System.Data
@model ViewModel

<div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.ReportResults.Columns)
                    {
                        <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.ReportResults.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.ReportResults.Columns)
                        {
                            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and here is my ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public DataTable ReportResults { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a judgment to the `DataType` of each column when displaying the value of each cell in the foreach loop, and make format changes to the final displayed value.

Use `style="text-align: xx"` for the td tag to make the column align center or right.

```
@using System.Data;
@using System.Globalization;
@model ViewModel  

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.ReportResults.Columns)
                {
                    <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (DataRow row in Model.ReportResults.Rows)
            {
            <tr>
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.ReportResults.Columns)
                {
                    if (col.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
                    { 
                       <td style="text-align:center">
                            @DateTime.Parse(row[col.ColumnName].ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault)
                        </td>
                    }
                    else if (col.DataType == typeof(decimal))
                    {
                          <td  style="text-align: right">
                            @decimal.Parse(row[col.ColumnName].ToString()).ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                        </td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the result :

[image]